vs code macro for wrapping code in if statement
i want to create a macro for wrapping a selected line of code in if statement in vs code. i stumbled upon this youtube video about macros in vs code so i tried imitating the 'ifWrap' in the video but for some reason it just doesn't seem to work. first download the macro-commander extension. then paste the this code in settings.json file and create the snippet need for it. and that's it, everything should have worked but it didn't so here is the code,
"editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "name": "iff"
        }
      },
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "true"
        }
      },
      "cursorLineEnd",
      "cursorDown",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"

this is the snippet that it uses(it doesn't have scope i don't know why but it is not allowed for some reason),
"iff":{
    "prefix": "iff",
    "body": [
        "if ($1) {",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "iff",
}

please help me and thank you.
i tried finding article related to it, tried asking questions to chatgpt, notebooklm, gemini but it didn't worked.

use variable TM_SELECTED_TEXT or TM_CURRENT_LINE, select text, type snippet prefix, type tab, selected text will be inserted

I'm really sorry but I'm beginner so i would really appreciate if you could show me the code instead.

I think problem is with comma after "description": "iff". This macro is in JSON format, and the last item in JSON should not have a trailling comma. So, just try to remove the last comma :)

use variable $TM_SELECTED_TEXT in snippet

select text
type snippet prefix
type tab
selected text will be inserted

"iff":{
    "prefix": "iff",
    "body": [
        "if ($TM_SELECTED_TEXT) {",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "iff"
}


@RushikeshAundhakar if this answer solves the problem you can mark it as such

sorry i made a silly mistake while writing it, it was "no man it just seem to work. but thanks for responding to the question" forgot to add 'doesn't' after 'just' in my comment. sorry again.

@RushikeshAundhakar I just tried and it works, you have to do the steps exactly as I gave them, select the text and immediately type the prefix
